# Error Sending Broadcast Intent when trying to save Cache file

Tags: android, android-file

im trying to save cache file (now example file) my CacheOperator class:

```
public class CacheOperator {

Context c;

public void saveSth() {
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
            fos = c.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I've overrided all context methods using default alt+enter keys.

When code gets to the checked place, app stops and there is exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.app.partyme/pl.app.partyme.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4940)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.app.partyme.tools.CacheOperator.saveSth(CacheOperator.java:49)
    at pl.app.partyme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
```

Should I first create this file somewhow or what?

Comment: I don't see Context c; getting initialized/assigned anywhere

Comment: @dymmeh could u help me with that?

Comment: Added an answer that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context "c" is null. Seeing that you're calling this method from an activity, pass the context from your activity into your method. Note the `Context` parameter in the method declaration

```
public void saveSth(Context c) {
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
            fos = c.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Your call to the method from within your activity would be something like:

```
cacheOperator.saveSth(this);
```